# Homebrew Apache Issues Post MacPorts Removal

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, homebrew, macports

I removed MacPorts completely following their guideline [here](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html). uninstaling all ports and then removing all folders

```
sudo rm -rf \ /opt/local \ /Applications/DarwinPorts \ /Applications/MacPorts \ /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.* \ /Library/Receipts/DarwinPorts*.pkg \ /Library/Receipts/MacPorts*.pkg \ /Library/StartupItems/DarwinPortsStartup \ /Library/Tcl/darwinports1.0 \ /Library/Tcl/macports1.0 \ ~/.macports
```

I then installed homebrew, dnsmasq and MySQL. The latter two I installed using Brew and Apache I wanted to run natively. Now the isue seems to be that Apache is still running via Macports.

```
ps ax | grep httpd
  254   ??  Ss     0:00.72 /opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
  258   ??  S      0:00.02 /opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
  259   ??  S      0:00.01 /opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
  262   ??  S      0:00.01 /opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
 1811   ??  S      0:00.01 /opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
 1812   ??  S      0:00.01 /opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
 1818   ??  S      0:00.01 /opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
 1820   ??  S      0:00.01 /opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
 1826   ??  S      0:00.02 /opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
 1857   ??  S      0:00.02 /opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
 2336   ??  S      0:00.01 /opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
 3720 s000  S+     0:00.00 grep httpd
```

This although all ports have been removed as well as all folders related to MacPorts. I also think all launchers have been removed. How could httpd be loaded now?

Other issue is that the DocumentRoot does not load the default documentRoot 
`DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"` from `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` nor `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` . It seems to load the old MacPorts documentRoot, but from where? All files and folders are gone as far as I know. And when I check for it, it does show the new DocumentRoot

```
sudo apachectl -V | grep -i SERVER_CONFIG_FILE | cut -f2 -d'"' | xargs grep -i '^DocumentRoot' | cut -f2 -d'"'
/Library/WebServer/Documents
```

And when I unloaded and loaded OSX's Apache I did get an error message showing my vhost was loaded:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
Password:
jaspersmbp:etc jasper$ sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
jaspersmbp:etc jasper$ apachectl
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
AH00526: Syntax error on line 41 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:
Invalid command 'VirtualDocumentRoot', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

But opening localhost still loads wrong or old DocumentRoot

Here the hosts file atm

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost jaspersmbp.local wordpress.local joomla.local
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost

# My local aliases
```

And here the VirtualHost at `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` I added to loaded local domains with *dev on the fly

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/jasper/webdesign"
    ServerName vhosts.dev
    ServerAlias *.dev
    UseCanonicalName Off
    LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
    ErrorLog "/Users/jasper/webdesign/vhosts-error_log"
    <Directory "/Users/jasper/webdesign/*">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

Running apachectl seems to restart MacPorts' Apache, but I cannot find it in .bashrc nor .bash_profile in my $PATH.

And my PATH

```
echo $PATH
/Users/jasper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/jasper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/jasper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/jasper/.rvm/bin
```

Questions are:

1. How can I stop the wrong ghost Apache daemon
2. How can I find where the document root is really loaded from and change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6602475 indicating that to stop both httpd processes from stopping and to stop the error I saw in my log stating

```
11/24/14 4:53:29.105 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (org.apache.httpd) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

that I had to use

```
sudo apachectl stop
sudo killall -9 httpd
```

the main things seems to have been that I needed to killall old running httpd processes. After that new hosts created in the host file started to work just fine.

And when I checked for the daemon I saw:

```
ps ax |grep httpd
 5798   ??  Ss     0:00.30 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
 5799   ??  S      0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
 5800   ??  S      0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
 5801   ??  S      0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
 5802   ??  S      0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

again. Finally OSX is running the Apache show again.